# Text with description pictures floating next to it

Tags: html, css, image, icons

Hi im kind of new to coding, but eager to learn, im trying to make a new website from scratch and wanted to set up a picture on the left and then next to it on the right something like this...[This is the closest i could find.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukMvo.png)
i can get the image on the left and the icons and text on the right, just not the text to the right of the icons... and cant seem to find any examples. If someone could give me a hand i would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to implement ? Lookup Bootstrap grid for more help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Also you can show your code to make your question more clear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Bootstrap grid system</h1>

    <p>select from 12</p>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img.png" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        GG
        <h1>GLHF</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

I think this is what you want. In other words, just add text and img link in the html and in css style sheet, use `float: left` and `padding`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response but those things dont seem to work, when i use that, the icon and text move under the picture to the left and not along side, i have also tried with the text-aline property for the text and the float for the image but nothing... i will attach a crude image of what i am trying to achieve [link] (https://imgur.com/xDmFMnP). hopefully someone can help, its driving me crazy.